# JavaScript Conflict in Fivestar Module

Tags: 7, javascript, rating

I have added [Fivestar Module](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) as a Field (***Widget***: Rated while Viewing) in my content type.

Before Adding the Module, My display was fine as in the picture below:
[image]

After Adding Fivestar, the display changes to 
[image]

Adding more field will break the layout and goes to Horizontal scrolling of the browser.

The jQuery in my Theme starts like this:

```
(function($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {


// To understand behaviors, see https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors
    Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
```

And the jQuery in Fivestar module start like:

```
(function($){ // Create local scope.

Drupal.behaviors.fivestar = {
  attach: function (context) {
    $(context).find('div.fivestar-form-item').once('fivestar', function() {
```

I am pretty sure this is due to JavaScript conflict, but I am not sure how to resolve this, edit the Fivestar's JavaScript directly? or is there anything I can do in my custom theme to resolve this issue?

Have anyone come across this situation? how did you resolve it?

Comment: Or it may be an un-terminated tag somewhere. You can move out the fivestar jquery and see if the layout will still be broken. Can diagnose in this way.

Comment: Yes actually, if I move the fivestar's jquery the layout doesn't break, but I need that jquery for fivestar to work perfectly, or else the clicking event doesn't satisfy what it should do.